# jQuery - modify HTML string

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Could someone tell me how I can modify the html before I insert it into the document?

This is an AJAX call:

```
url: "http://localhost/cart/public/admin/album",
success: function(html) {
```

This is the result of the AJAX call:

```
<div class="main-content slide-in">
    <h1>Create Album</h1>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

All I want to do is change the color of the `h1` tag. I have added this code

```
url: "http://localhost/cart/public/admin/album",
success: function(html) {
    $(html).find('h1').css('color','red');
    $('aside').after(html);
```

However this has no effect. The jQuery selector does seem to be working though.

```
url: "http://localhost/cart/public/admin/album",
success: function(html) {
    $(html).find('h1').css('color','red');
    console.log($(html).find('h1').length);
    $('aside').after(html);
```

Using `console.log` correct outputs 1. So it is finding the h1. For some reason though the css style isn't being applied.

I am bit stuck. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Are you trying to change the text color or the background color?

Comment: Can you make http://jsfiddle.net demo of this problem?

Comment: Your code should work, are you sure your page does not contain any rules to hide the elements you are adding?

Comment: Are you missing a dot before "aside"?

Comment: Is there any compelling reason not to add it to the DOM and *then* change its css?

Comment: And @leo.vingi has a point. If 'aside' is a class applied to some of your elements, you need to use $('.aside'). If it is the id of an element, you need to use $('#aside')

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you're changing the color and then adding the unchanged string to the DOM. Try this:

```
success: function(html) {
    var $html = $(html);
    $html.find('h1').css('color','red');
    $('aside').after($html);
```

Comment: great answer :) it could be simplified as follows: $html.find('h1').css('color', 'red').end().insertAfter('aside')

Comment: Note: If you want the root element from the string, you can't use `find` on it, since the variable *is* the root element.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer here actually wasted quite a lot of my time. At least it isn't generic. This is what figured out after sometime.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/~yoelusa/the-url-of-your-string.html",
  success: function(htmldata) {
    var $html = $("<div/>").append( htmldata );
    // make your changes on the html string, see some example bellow relevant to my htmlstring
    $html.find('#left').html("");
    $html.find('#right').html("");
    $html.find('.commentlist').remove();
    // when you are ready to insert your string somewhere call the html() function, in my example I inserted it in an iframe
    $("iframe").attr("srcdoc", $html.html() );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`$(html).find('h1').css('color', 'red').parent().insertAfter('aside');`

Comment: this would only insert the h1 and not the entire html element

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` to the css style:

```
$(html).find('h1').css("color", "red !important");
```

Comment: You can't use !important in a .css call.